# java.io.IOException The device is not ready

Tags: java, windows, io

I'm trying to create a new file on a directory shared in a network. However I get this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: The device is not ready
 at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
 at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:947)
 at pdfconverter.PdfConverter.main(PdfConverter.java:96)
```

The path of the directory is correct and the directory is shared with "everyone" in this network.

Does anyone has a solution to this problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you create this file outside of Java? (For example using the command prompt, or by saving a small file in the same directory using Notepad.)

Comment: Yes, I can create a file manually.

Comment: Add some source code to your question, and say what the pathname actually is.

Comment: I found what was wrong. The base directory was correct but I was trying to save the file in a subfolder (which was not created). The full path must exist before saving. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @EduardoMelo - this solved my problem too. Consider re-writing your Comment as an Answer to your own Question, so it can be Accepted or Upvoted.